# Typescript increase score in case of collision

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js

I'm making a game in Pixi JS where if my cat collides with a mouse, the score increases with +1. Now my problem is that score increases not by one if the two collide but by like 30 or something with each collision. Even after all the mice are deleted from the game and the score is set to zero it still keeps counting?

This is the code for increasing the score when the mouse and cat collide, which does not work

```js
 for (const mouse of this.mice) {
      mouse.update(delta);
      
      if (this.collision(this.cat, mouse)) {
        // console.log("CAT ATTACK!!!!");
        this.pixi.stage.removeChild(mouse);
        //setTimeout(() => {  this.interface.addScore(1); }, 5000);
        this.interface.addScore(1);
        //this.interface.score = Mouse.length;
        
      }
    }
```

This is the code I have in my ui.TS file

```js
export class ui extends PIXI.Container {

    scoreField:PIXI.Text
    score:number = 0
    private game: Game;

    constructor(game: Game){
        super();
        this.game = game;
        const style = new PIXI.TextStyle({
            fontFamily: 'ArcadeFont',
            fontSize: 40,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fill: ['#ffffff']
        })
    
        this.scoreField = new PIXI.Text(`Score : 0`, style)
        this.addChild(this.scoreField)
        this.scoreField.x = 10
        this.scoreField.y = 10
    }

    addScore(n:number) {
        this.score += n
        this.scoreField.text = `Score : ${this.score}`
    }

}
```

Lastly if the player loses the score gets set to zero, and I deleted all the mice from te game. I thought this made sure the score couldn't start counting again but it its still adding and getting above zero even if there is no mouse and cat to collide?

```js
// when the Dog is the only survivor
    if (
      this.pixi.stage.children.filter((object) => object instanceof Dog)
        .length === 1 &&
        this.pixi.stage.children.filter((object) => object instanceof Cat)
        .length === 0 
    ) {
      console.log("YOU LOSE");
      let text = new PIXI.Text("You LOSE!!", { fill: ["#ffffff"] });
      text.x = this.pixi.screen.width / 2;
      text.y = this.pixi.screen.height / 2;
      this.pixi.stage.addChild(text);
      for (const dog of this.dogs) {
        dog.update(delta);
          this.pixi.stage.removeChild(dog);
          for (const mouse of this.mice) {
            this.pixi.stage.removeChild(mouse);
            this.interface.score = 0; 
          }
          
          this.interface.score = 0; 
        }
```

Edit: I fixed this problem by only updating the score when the cat is still in game

Comment: can you prepare minimal reproduction of this problem at https://www.pixiplayground.com/ or similar site? Will be much easier to help.

Comment: but from look : you are looping through `this.mice` but you are only doing `this.pixi.stage.removeChild(mouse);`  - so you dont remove also from `this.mice` ? (In other words `this.mice` collection is not changed?)

Comment: The `update` function fires multiple times per second, so the condition for the collision returns true multiple times per second. You could try a boolean like `let dead = false`, and then when the mouse collides set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

You could flag the mouse with `mouse.dead = true` after a collision. You only count the score when `mouse.dead` is still set to false.

```
for (const mouse of this.mice) {
      if(mouse.dead === false) {
          mouse.update(delta);
  
          if (this.collision(this.cat, mouse)) {
               mouse.dead = true;
               this.pixi.stage.removeChild(mouse);
               this.interface.addScore(1);
          }
      }
}
```

Like @domis86 says, if you don't want to end up with an array that only has objects that are not relevant anymore (mice that are not on the stage), you should remove the mice from the array. The tricky part is that you are altering an array while still looping through it, you can solve that by looping backwards.

```
 for (let i = this.mice.length-1; i>-1; i--) {
      let mouse = this.mice[i];
      mouse.update(delta);
      
      if (this.collision(this.cat, mouse)) {
        this.pixi.stage.removeChild(mouse);
        this.interface.addScore(1);
        this.mice.splice(i, 1)
      }
 }
```